# Make IPython Notebook accept connections only from given address/subnet

Tags: emacs, ipython

I'm running Notebook server on remote machine and want to somehow protect it. Unfortunately I cannot use password authentication (because if I do so then I can't use `ein`, an emacs package for ipython notebooks).

The other obvious solution is to make IPython Notebook accept connections only from my local machine's ip, but it seems that there is no regular way to do this with ipython configs. Maybe I'm missing something?

Or maybe there is another way to achieve my goal?

UPDATE: here's a bug about it posted to EIN tracker: https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook/issues/57.

UPDATE2: thanks to millejoh (`ein` developer), now `ein` should work with password-protected notebooks, so the question is not actual anymore. Thanks everyone for your replies!

Comment: What about doing it on the remote machine side?
Make the Notebook server run on a given port, and set the settings for that port so that that port only accepts connections from your local machine's IP. Then you don't even need to play with the ipython configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the port for iPython to a port that will only be used by iPython.
And then restrict access to that port to only you local machine's IP.

To set the port:

Edit the ipython_notebook_config.py file and insert or edit the line:

```
c.NotebookApp.port = 7777
```

where you change 7777 to the port of your choice.

Assuming the remote machine in Linux. You can then use iptables to block access to that port except from your local machine:

```
iptables -I INPUT \! --src 1.2.3.4 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 7777 -j DROP  # if it's not 1.2.3.4, drop it
```

where you change 1.2.3.4 to your local ip and 7777 to the port you have iPython working on.

Sources:

For iPython configs: [Docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/public_server.html)

For blocking IPs : [StackExchange](https://serverfault.com/questions/146569/iptables-how-to-allow-only-one-ip-through-specific-port) [cyberciti](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-6-how-to-block-outgoing-access-to-selectedspecific-ip-address.html)

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks! It partially solves my problem. Partially -- because in addition to main desktop sometimes I connect to IPython machine from the laptop through vpn with dynamically assigned IP (and I have no permission to configure vpn).

Comment: Is the VPN part of the same network as the iPython server?

Comment: They're in different subnets, but both inside internal corporate network.

Comment: Then maybe there is a way to allow the whole internal corporate network in addition to your main desktop. It kind of depends who you want to protect it from.

Answer (score 0):

I dont found anything about other authentication way on ipython website, then you can have right. 
Here http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/security.html is something about ipython trust. Maybe it will be sufficient for you.